# facebook iframe - getting facebook logo instead of a popup authentication

Tags: facebook, facebook-iframe, server-side

(using server-side flow) i have a facebook application that is attached to a facebook page through one of the tabs, which makes the application within an iframe.  i use the following code below which works to get the access token but only when the users click on the facebook logo and authenticate the app.  my question is what should i do so i can get a better user experience instead of showing the facebook logo stuff.
thanks.

ON pageLoad()......
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string code = Request.QueryString["code"];
        if (HttpContext.Current.Session["fbAccessToken"] != null)
        {
            authToken = HttpContext.Current.Session["fbAccessToken"].ToString();
        }

```
    if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(authToken))
    {
        thisUserFBID.Value = HttpContext.Current.Session["fbUserId"].ToString();
    }
    else if (code == "" || code == null)
    {
        Response.Redirect(appHelp.GetCodeUrl());
        //Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "alert", "shareMe();", true);
    }
    else
    {
        authToken = appHelp.GetAccessToken(code);
        Session["access_token"] = authToken;
        HttpContext.Current.Session["fbAccessToken"] = authToken;

        try
        {
            var fb = new FacebookClient();
            fb.AccessToken = authToken;
            dynamic me = fb.Get("me");
            thisUserFBID.Value = (string)me.id;
            HttpContext.Current.Session["fbUserId"] = thisUserFBID.Value;
            if (me.locale != null)
                lang = (string)me.locale;
            else
                lang = "en_US";
            HttpContext.Current.Session["lang"] = lang;
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            //Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "alert", "shareMe();", true);
            //Response.Redirect(appHelp.GetCodeUrl());
        }

    }
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Huh?  You don't want to have the user know what they're logging into?  I'm confused.  In a page tab application, you can either prompt them for authorizing the app or if they're logged in already, show them the good stuff.  I don't know what would make a better user experience than that.